# Python programming, Zybooks unexpected character legend

Tags: python

```py
def selection_sort_descend_trace(lst):
    for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
        max_ind = i
        for j in range(i + 1, len(lst)):
            if lst[j] > lst[max_ind]:
                max_ind = j
        lst[i], lst[max_ind] = lst[max_ind], lst[i]
        print(' '.join([str(x) for x in lst]))
        
    return lst


if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
    selection_sort_descend_trace(numbers)
```

So with this code, I typed in "Zybooks", ran it, an I received an unexpected character legend? I don't know which one it is that has a space.

Comment: The code runs fine for me. Please describe in more detail how you are running the code. If you get an error message -- what is the full message? What line is throwing the error?

Comment: file:///C:/Users/15135/OneDrive/Pictures/Screenshots/2021-04-14.png     Heres the link for it, where I got the error message at.

Comment: Please ask the question in such a way that it doesn't depend upon external links (especially links which do not appear to be public). You can copy the error message as text in the body of the question.

Comment: 40 10 30 20 
40 30 10 20 
40 30 20 10 The output is these numbers right here and the error shows up at the end its like a straight line going down behind 20, 20, and 10. When I at the special character legend to figure out what this means is "Space: An unexpected space was detected in the output."

Comment: Your code is fine. I've never heard of "Zybooks" but it seems that it must be buggy. Look at their documentation to see if there is anything special you need to do to run code there. If not, file a bug report.